# Dynamic harmonic regression: estimated coefficients are zero

Tags: regression, time-series

I fitted a dynamic harmonic regression model with specified features. However, the summary of the training model indiates one of the features has an estimated coefficient of zero and its corresponding standard error is also zero (it could be the case that the coefficient and standard errors were displayed as zeros but indeed non-zeros).  Have someone seen this before? Should I be worried?